# connecting to an api using php and curl with username, password and cookies

Tags: php, json, api, curl, cookies

I am getting the error bellow when making a request to an api:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Server: nginx/1.9.3 Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 12:04:35 GMT Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="application" X-Powered-By: Undertow 1 Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/ecocashGateway-preprod; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 09-Feb-2017 12:04:35 GMT Set-Cookie: PAYMENTS_CLUSTER=PAY_02; path=/

Here is my php and curl request:

```
$url = 'https://payonline.econet.co.zw/ecocashGateway-preprod/payment/v1/transactions/amount'; 
//Initiate cURL. 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-length:'.strlen($jsonDataEncoded))
);
```

Comment: What is the value of $url? This is likely your problem since you're getting a "401 Unauthorized Server" error.

Comment: $url = 'https://payonline.econet.co.zw/ecocashGateway-preprod/payment/v1/transactions/amount';

    / /Initiate cURL.
    $ch = curl_init($url);

Comment: I don't know that there's anything we can do for you as it is now. The 401 seems to indicate your login is wrong. Check the duplicate, as there's a wealth of information on how to do this

Comment: can i have the link to the duplicate?